# Add Slideshow in Category page

Tags: magento, magento-1.8

I'm using Shopper Queldorei Magento Theme which it uses Revolution Slider, and I want to add a slideshow in category page like this: [ultimo theme](http://themeforest.net/item/ultimo-fluid-responsive-magento-theme/full_screen_preview/3231798)

What should I doing please.

Best regards

Comment: Using magento banner slider plugin, you can create slider for the categories

Answer (score 0):

Not sure how slideshow is implemented in Shopper, but you can use slider Revolution from NWDthemes and create different slideshows for different categories.

Basically all you need is update **Custom Layout Update** field in **Custom Design** tab to add slideshow block to the header or instead of category image.

Check this article for reference - http://nwdthemes.com/2015/04/29/slideshow-for-category-page-with-slider-revolution-magento-extension/